# jupyter notebook can not import keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have installed Keras and TensorFlow-GPU but when I try to import these libraries into Jupiter notebook there is an error

```
Keras-applications        1.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard               2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu            2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-gpu-estimator  2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.19.2                   pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.4.0.44                 pypi_0    pypi
pip                       19.2.3                   py37_0
```

here are the libraries using     conda list .
and here is the error that jupyter displays to me :

> ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 import keras
> 2 from keras.models import Sequential
> 3 from keras.layers import Dense,  Activation
> 4 import numpy as np
> 5
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'

I try this one in anaconda environment:

> pip3 install keras
>
> Requirement already satisfied: keras in
> c:\users\msi-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
> (2.4.3) Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.1 in
> c:\users\msi-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
> (from keras) (1.19.4) Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.14 in
> c:\users\msi-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
> (from keras) (1.5.4) Requirement already satisfied: h5py in
> c:\users\msi-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
> (from keras) (3.1.0) Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in
> c:\users\msi-pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages
> (from keras) (5.3.1)

I'm grateful if you help me.

P. S :
I realized that in order to import keras /tensorflow from the second version on (tensorflow>=2.0.0 ) i have to use import tensorflow.keras
And everything will be good.

Comment: I do not see a package called "keras" in that list, that is why it does not work.

Comment: but a few minutes ago i use pip install keras and it said that the keras was installed successfully. but I realized that I should use tensorflow.keras , is there any difference between keras and tensorflow.keras algorithms and sub packages ? thank you

Comment: Try `pip list` when your `conda` environment is activated. Check if `keras` is in there.

Comment: i try pip list in conda environment but no keras module is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using tensorflow >= 2.0, then import keras using

```py
from tensorflow import keras
```

Common convention is to import it `as kr`

Comment: Thank you i realize that after tensorflow 2 i sholud import tensorflow.keras in order to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell me if **you're using multiple versions of python on the same device**, if so please check if you've installed **TensorFlow on the same version of python which you're using for jupyter notebook**, to check that and install again:

1. Go to the **path where you've installed python**(which you're using for
   jupyter notebook) if you've installed anaconda then **go to the path
   where anaconda is installed** and follow the procedure.
2. Go to the **site-packages folder** in the **path** of Anaconda or python.
3. Check if all the dependencies of TensorFlow and TensorFlow are
   **installed there**.
4. If you can't find it then **add the current python version to
   environment variables**, see:
   [https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-set-python-path#:~:text=SETTING%20PATH%20IN%20PYTHON%201%20Right%20click%20on,on%20Ok%20button%3A%209%20Click%20on%20Ok%20button%3A](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-set-python-path#:%7E:text=SETTING%20PATH%20IN%20PYTHON%201%20Right%20click%20on,on%20Ok%20button%3A%209%20Click%20on%20Ok%20button%3A)
   and
   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-setup-anaconda-path-to-environment-variable/
5. After you've **added the current version of python to the environment path**
   variables then follow this link to install TensorFlow:
   [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-python-tensorflow-in-windows/#:~:text=%20%20%201%20Step%201%3A%20Click%20on,done%20with%20the%20use%20of%20following...%20More%20](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-python-tensorflow-in-windows/#:%7E:text=%20%20%201%20Step%201%3A%20Click%20on,done%20with%20the%20use%20of%20following...%20More%20)
   and
   https://machinelearningspace.com/installing-tensorflow-2-0-in-anaconda-environment/

Then again follow **step 2 and 3** and if it's still not appearing in the **site-packages folder** then follow this link:
https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-work-with-Keras-on-a-Jupyter-notebook-using-Tensorflow-as-backend
for some details(not that helpful)

Also, **Try installing Keras by this command:**

```
pip3 install Keras
```

If you're using **one version of python** then please check if **jupyter and TensorFlow are installed in the same Virtual Environment**
Please tell me if it works or not.

Comment: Thank you but i realized that i should import tensorflow.keras because i am using tensorflow 2

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you have imported keras, but in past even I have faced a similar issue. What I had done is i did something like this

```
import keras
```

which is wrong! We have to import it like this

```
from tensorflow import keras
```

which worked fine for me! Hope this Helps you!